# UniFi cross-VLAN routing

Tags: networking, vlan

We have a UniFi network divided into various VLANs.
172.17.x.x is the guest network, but I would like clients on this network to access a printer at 172.16.20.2

I have fiddled with various firewall rules, but without success. Could anyone please illuminate me on how to poke a hole between the VLANs so that the one printer becomes available to users of the 172.17-subnet?

Comment: Model number of the VLAN capable router you are trying to configure would be useful. What have you tried as far as firewall rules?

Comment: If there is a VLAN capable switch in the mix a SVI with acls may be useful.

Comment: The gateway is a UniFi Security Gateway 4P running firmware 4.4.22.5086057 and the switches are all UniFi running firmware 3.9.42.9152

Comment: As for the rules I have tried, I've tested both LAN and WAN In/Out/Local. I'm sure I'm missing something..

Basically, I've defined 
- Rule applied = Before predefined rules
- Action = Accept
- Source = Network: VLAN17
- Destination = Address: 172.16.20.2